# Stop execution of JS events loaded by a script loaded in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a application in JS where I have to load parts of the application with AJAX.
When the AJAX function is completed, the script is executed.

But when I want to load another part of my application, I'd like to know how could I remove all events and variables binded to the part of my app I just loaded ?

For example :

```
$('#loadPart1').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url : url,
        success : function(xhr){
            // xhr contains javascript to execute 
            // and events I want to stop executing afterward
            $('body').html(xhr);
    });
});

// load another part of the app
// should stop execute previous JS
// and now executes just loaded JS from this AJAX load.
$('#loadPart2').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url : url,
        success : function(xhr){
            // xhr contains javascript to execute
            // and replace old script
            $('body').html(xhr);
    });
});
```

I hope you understand what I want to explain. It's just a code to help, this is not my real code, so don't bother with it, it is just an image for you to understand the problem.

'Cause I already have an application, but when I load something in AJAX, previous scripts events still executes.

Is there a technique, a pattern which can stop the execution of Javascript I don't want. I'd like to remove all events but without calling them explicitly.

Comment: I don't think you really want to stop the execution of your script, but just unbind events in it. See unbind method : http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: If those events are bound to elements that are being removed, the events will be automatically removed with them. If you're using event delegation, you should keep that in mind and delegate from an element that will be removed with the page so that those events will also be automatically cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an event handler you can use the jQuery event handler `.off()` and `.on()` instead `.click()`

http://api.jquery.com/off/

http://api.jquery.com/on/